# Scaling circle image in browser - works fine for one image, doesn't for 2 images

Tags: css, image, browser, render, src

I encountered an awkward situation. I have this image:

[image]

This image looks sharp in the browser if i use this code:

```
<img width="30" src="img/add.jpg" /><img width="30" src="img/add.jpg" />
```

but looks smooth when i use this code:

```
<img width="30" src="img/add.jpg" />
```

So i guess the problem is that multiple images causes the problem, if i display only one it looks smooth. But the question is why ?

**The sharp images:**

[image]

**The smooth image:**

[image]

Comment: what is the difference in generated html? Also there is a typo in your first code `editjpg`

Comment: How wide is the parent element and how many images are you showing? My guess is that the images together are too wide for the parent body or something. This is definitely a html issue and has nothing to do with blade, laravel, src or any of your other tags.

Comment: Try put them in a complete html page (with <html><body> etc) and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Because you first thought it was Blade fault:

It's really not possible that Blade could cause any problem with displaying image. Blade just generates HTML and if it's the same as HTML you want to achieve it's not Blade fault.

You should rather look at other problems (container width), extra spaces between images and not look a problem in Blade itself if it generated good HTML.

**EDIT**

I don't know why it happens but I can confirm it happens. But after some refreshes it looks fine again in my Firefox. Possible solutions:

- create image file that will be 30px so you won't need to set `width` attribute
- <strike>or try to scale your image first to some other width - I haven't tried it but image is itself 118px width, when you try to scale it to 30px, you  3,93333 ratio, you might try to convert it in some graphic program to 120px, then the ratio would be 4.</strike>

**EDIT2**

I've checked above and only 1st solution will work. You need to create image that has exact dimensions and don't use browser scaling. It seems that browser cannot handle scaling so good so for circles you will see some effects you don't want to so you need to prepare image in graphic program.

Comment: @paulalexandru There is no need to try anything, it's just logic and reason. Blade is just a templating engine, it makes creating the code / markup a little easier and more readable. But in the end, it all compiles down to the same code / markup you would write without a templating engine. It doesn't make your output look different, just the code. So there is no possible way it could have anything to do with Blade. And, as you stated yourself, there aren't any differences in the output-code / markup. And blade has nothing to do with the interpretation of the markup, it's your browser's job.